# How to execute method for struct which is field for other struct

Tags: go

I created such 2 structs:

```
type HostsFile struct {
    path    string
    masters string
    nodes   string
}

type AnsInstance struct {
    name      string
    url       string
    yamlPath  string
    user      string
    pass      string
    branch    string
    hostsFile *HostsFile
}
```

`HostsFile` struct have such methods:

```
func (p *HostsFile) SetMasters(masters string) {
    p.masters = masters
}

func (p *HostsFile) SetNodes(nodes string) {
    p.nodes = nodes
}
```

and `AnsInstance` has such one which is using methods from `HostFile` struct:

```
func (p *AnsInstance) PrepInstExec(masters string, nodes string) {
    p.hostsFile.SetMasters(masters)
    p.hostsFile.SetNodes(nodes)
    p.hostsFile.GenerateHostsFile()
}
```

When im executing `PrepInstExec` in such way:

```
ansInstance.PrepInstExec("lalala,fafafaf", "bakuka,matata")
```

Im getting error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4ccba3]

goroutine 1 [running]:
card-installer/ansexec.(*HostsFile).SetMasters(...)
        /home/holo/go/src/card-installer/ansexec/ansexec.go:19
card-installer/ansexec.(*AnsInstance).PrepInstExec(0xc0000c5e90, 0x6d1a2c, 0xe, 0x6d15b9, 0xd)
        /home/holo/go/src/card-installer/ansexec/ansexec.go:145 +0x53
main.main()
        /home/holo/go/src/card-installer/main.go:101 +0x84e
exit status 2
```

What am i doing wrong? Is there posibility to exec methods of one struct which is embedded to other?

**EDIT:**

I am creating new `AnsInstance` in such way:

```
func NewAnsInstance(name string, url string, path string) *AnsInstance {
    p := new(AnsInstance)
    p.name = name
    p.url = url
    p.yamlPath = path
    p.branch = "master"
    return p
}
```

Comment: always do error checking

Comment: side-note: avoid the use of `new` in cases like this. It obscures the fact that you're creating a pointer variable, and it doens't allow for you to initialise fields in a single statement. use `p := AnsInstance{}` or `p := &AnsInstance{}` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since hostsFile *HostsFile is of type pointer, the default/zero value while creating an instance of the struct will be nil. So calling methods on nil will panic.

Comment: That was it i removed pointer type from AnsInstance struct and it is working. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

maybe is hostsFile' nil??

```
func main() {
    ansInstance := NewAnsInstance("name", "url", "path")

    // add code and check hostsFile
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ansInstance)
}
```

Comment: I updated post with additionall information
Isnt "new" creating all struct fields?

Comment: If you do not understand, check the value in this way. comment update.

Comment: When i added pointer to empty variable in NewAnsInstance method it helped but below solution i think is better for me - to not use pointer in struct definition.